# Remove full url's from text file using unix awk/sed/grep

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file that in the form of tweets and I am having issues removing the full url's. An example of the textfile:

`index.html`:

```
this is a tweet that has info. http://google.com
this is a tweet that has an image. pic.twitter.com/a2y4H1b2Jq
```

I would like to create a new file that only has:

```
this is a tweet that has info.
this is a tweet that has an image.
```

Right now I am working with grep and I have

```
grep -oP "http://\K[^']+" final.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is URL always the last field?

Comment: what about `sed` if you want to remove those uris? perhaps expand a command like `sed -i 's#http://[a-z] # #g'` filewithuris.txt

Comment: Consider that you may need to, or it might be less confusing to, filter the file through grep more than once, as in `grep regex1 final.txt | grep regex2`.  It often makes sense to use multiple regexes to get variations of the matching behavior rather than trying to make one regex do everything.  You might have a regex that matches `https?://` to get the URLs that have a scheme, and another regex to match what looks like URLs that do not have a scheme.

Comment: `pic.twitter.com/a2y4H1b2Jq` is not a "full url". As a result, `grep`ping for `http....` is obviously not going to find it... Perhaps you should be a little more specific about what you are really trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/http[^ ]*//g' YourFile
```

[^ ]* is catching all characters which are not blank

Answer (score 1):

Depends how restrictive you want it to be.

Full URLs that start with HTTP and have separators around:

```
sed -e 's|\bhttp[^ ]*\.[^ ]*\b||g' test.html
```

Anything with a dot that has any separators around:

```
sed -e 's|\b[^ ]*\.[^ ]*\b||g' test.html
```